# how to create custom RangeBar(SeekBar) in android

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I'm trying to create a custom RangeBar on android, but so far couldn't find any approach to create such view:
[image: r]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a custom view, you will need to know calculus,geometry and geometric theory good luck.